What size of Wet Vac do I need to suck up very wet mud?
I have a project where I need to suck up some mud and transfer it to another location. What size of vacuum do I need? Can I suck it in and transfer it to another location at the same time?

a vacuum cleaner is not a pump ... you will have to use something else

A vacuum will struggle with the viscosity of the mud.

Perhaps you should post a photo

No. You need a pump

Unless it is muddy water,  what you want is a shovel.

Or possibly a bucket.

If you insist on using a wet vac for this purpose, the best you are going to be able to do is fill the vac, move it to where you want the mud, open it up and dump it out, move it back, repeat as necessary. Warning: a vacuum full of mud is going to be heavy, and the larger, the heavier. Think about how much a cubic foot of mud will weigh, then multiply it by the useful volume of the vac and add the weight of the vac itself...
If you edited your question to describe what you are actually trying to accomplish rather than focusing on this detail and this way of doing it, we might be able to suggest some alternatives.

A typical wet/dry vac, at least in my experience, is designed to suck in water, loose debris (think sand, sawdust, etc.) and other stuff and can handle some mud coming in. However, the output is always just air - i.e.., the stuff comes in, falls into the big bucket and stays there - the output isn't a "reverse" of the vacuum but simply pushing out the air that normally comes in when you use the vacuum, so a blower not an outbound pump.
I think most wet/dry vacs will have problems sucking in large quantities of mud, but even if they can handle that they still won't push it back out.
There are specialized tools that can do this, but not a general purpose vac.

There are a few wet vacs which can "pump" water to a limited degree!; they have a drain with a check valve, and only after enough water has been drawn in for the weight to overcome that do they start to drain through this (usually into a garden hose). I believe there was one specific brand that billed itself as the vacuum that can pump. But that doesn't get you any closer to moving mud.
